# How to get rid of 'minutes' in org-mode column view

Tags: emacs, formatting, org-mode

I am using Org-mode 8.0.2 and Emacs 24.1.1.

How to change format of time displayed in column view from 'hh:mm' to simply 'hh'?
So for 86 hours it would not be '86:00' but '86' instead.

I can do that for tasks with subtasks by executing

```
(setq org-time-clocksum-format '(:hours "%d" :require-hours t))
```

But usual time-cells still use old format.

My org-file:

```
* simple task 
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   9:00
:END:
* task with subtasks
** subtask 
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   9:00
:END:
```

My column-view:

```
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM(Task) %17Effort(Estimate){:}

#+BEGIN: columnview :maxlevel 3
| Task                 | Estimate |
|----------------------+----------|
| * simple task        |     9:00 |
| * task with subtasks |        9 |
| ** subtask           |     9:00 |
#+END:
```

As a workaround, I can enter some dummy subtasks for each task without subtasks and move estimate there and then by limiting :maxlevel property I can hide those dummy subtasks. This workaround has some limitations and it is not an elegant solution whatsever.

Comment: Have you tried something simple, like truncating by setting the effort to something like %2?  Modifying the format may bring problems when it comes time to calculate . . .

Comment: Using %2 has no effect, I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the solution was simpler than I thought...
Just use

```
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   9
:END:
```

Instead of

```
:PROPERTIES:
:Effort:   9:00
:END:
```

It seems it is not really a proper solution as it starts to think that effort is set in minutes and not in hours. But it works for me.